# Compare two tables, if value exists display 1, if value doesn't exist display 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

SQL SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE SNMASTER ( 
  SERIAL_NUMBER varchar(50),
  WORK_ORDER int(5),
  ASSY_ID int(3)
);
  
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS ( 
  SERIAL_NUMBER varchar(50),
  OPERATION_ID int(5),
  CREATED_ON DATETIME
);
  
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40877',56794,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40886',56794,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40895',56794,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40902',56794,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40911',56794,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40920',88545,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40939',88545,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40948',88545,841);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40957',97846,842);
INSERT INTO SNMASTER VALUES('0910A40966',97846,842);
  
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES('0910A40886',113,'2020-02-27 13:39:46');
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES('0910A40877',116,'2020-02-27 13:39:48');
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES('0910A40886',116,'2020-02-27 13:40:03');
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES('0910A40939',113,'2020-02-27 13:40:20');
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES('0910A40886',160,'2020-02-27 13:40:48');
```

I need my results displayed like this:

```
SERIAL_NUMBER  113  116  160
 0910A40877    0    1    0
 0910A40886    1    1    1
 0910A40895    0    0    0
 0910A40902    0    0    0
 0910A40911    0    0    0
```

It looks like the results display the first 5 rows from TABLE SNMASTER

Then it looks at TABLE TRANSACTIONS, and writes a 1 when there's an OPERATION_ID

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, not SQL Server or Oracle.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select sm.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from transactions t
                where t.serial_number = sm.serial_number and t.operation_id = 113
               )
       ) as has_113,
       (exists (select 1
                from transactions t
                where t.serial_number = sm.serial_number and t.operation_id = 116
               )
       ) as has_116,
       (exists (select 1
                from transactions t
                where t.serial_number = sm.serial_number and t.operation_id = 160
               )
       ) as has_160
from snmaster sm;
```

With an index on `transactions(serial_number, operation_id)`, this is probably the fastest method.

In MySQL, `exists` returns a boolean value.  The database treats `1` as true and `0` as false, which is why this does what you want.  In other databases you would need to wrap the `exists` in a `case` expression.

Comment: Very cool way of approaching these tables. I like it. Thank you!

Comment: How would I limit the query to only display the top 5 in MySQL?

Comment: I don't know how you are identifying "top".  But you would use `order by <whatever is used to define the top> limit 5`.

Comment: Ok, it looks like MySQL uses syntax: "limit (number)". I was specifically referring to the first 5 rows from the top. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.SERIAL_NUMBER,
sum(case when  b.OPERATION_ID = 113 then 1 else 0 end) as '113',
sum(case when  b.OPERATION_ID = 116 then 1 else 0 end) as '116',
sum(case when  b.OPERATION_ID = 160 then 1 else 0 end) as '160'
from SNMASTER a
left outer join TRANSACTIONS b on (a.SERIAL_NUMBER = b.SERIAL_NUMBER)
group by a.SERIAL_NUMBER
```